# Ping IPv6 Address with .Net does not work

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a simple ping to a host in my local network:

```
var ipString = "::ffff:192.168.178.20";

if (IPAddress.TryParse(ipString, out var ipaddr)){

    var reply = new Ping().Send(ipaddr, 5000);
    return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success ? "Good":"Bad"; //<- always returning "Bad"

}
```

The Ip Address gets parsed, but the ping runs into the 5s timeout. The ping works when I am using the windows console ('C:\ping ::ffff:192.168.178.20').

Does anyone has an idea what could be the reason for that behaviour?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar: Yes, as mentioned above the ping works from the windows command line

Comment: it's worth noting that `Send` has options you're not setting that are critical to how ICMP works. The `ping` command line tool _does_ set those options. You should check the value `Status` is set to because that will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @Mgetz Status is 'timeout'. But the PingOptions was a good hint. I will try to figure out the differences between the windows cmd and the .Net ping..

Comment: Also be aware that `Ping` is disposable and you should be using it in a `using` block. I'd also highly suggest setting the `DontFragment` option based on my own experiences with the unmanaged ICMPAPI.

Comment: Where do you define ipaddr?  Your parse outputs into ip.

Comment: @Duston the ipaddr comes from an GRPC call. There I am using the ServerCallContext.Peer property on the ServerCallContext. Then I am parsing the Peer property (in this case 'ipv6:[::ffff:192.168.178.20]:50659' manually to '::ffff:192.168.178.20'.

Comment: @Mgetz good point. I will change my code. Thanks

Comment: My point is you set ipString = '::ffff:192.168.178.20" and parse that into ip, but your new Ping() uses ipaddr as a parameter.  And you don't have ipaddr set to anything in your code.

Comment: @Duston: you are right, but that was just a typo. I fixed it. Of cause I am using the parsed IP Address for the ping.